# age "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config

Tags: next.js, next-auth, generatestaticparams

This is my file

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import { SupabaseAdapter } from "@auth/supabase-adapter"
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters';

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    }),
  ],
  adapter: SupabaseAdapter({
    url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL as string,
    secret: process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY as string,
  }) as Adapter,
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

and during the build I receive this error "Error: Page "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config."

I've no how to refactor my code

I've read documentation, but I didn't find suitable answear

Comment: did you find a solution?